# Does it hurt performance to dynamically link a shared library that won't be used?

Tags: python

I have a C++ program (in fact it is a dll) which dynamically links to another shared library (python dll), this program has two occasions to be used.

In occasion A, the program will make function calls to that dynamically linked shared library while in occasion B, the program will not.

My question is if I build the program specially for occasion B without linking to the shared library, will I gain performance comparing to the case where I link the shared library without actually using it?

Comment: I'm thinking "inconsequential time" ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really dependent on several factors: What OS, what shared library, and what the application actually does. Possibly also how the shared library is built.

In general, it's not a particularly large penalty, since shared libraries are demand-loaded and use position independent addressing [PIC] (PC-relative, and similar). What this means is that the shared library is being loaded only when it actually is used, and that there's "no work" to load the library. This is something that OS designers and system architects think a lot about, because for many applications that are performance sensitive (for example compilers or web-services), a badly designed shared library system will make performance BAD.

It is of course possible to configure when building the shared library. At least the use of PIC aspect of this, so if the person/company configuring the build of the shared library "wants to", it could be badly configured and worse than zero effect.

To this you have to add any initialization that the shared library does. Well designed shared libraries does "on demand" or "lazy" initialization, in other words, doesn't do much initialization until it's actually required. Again, the details of exactly which library - including how that was configured when it was built - can make a huge difference here.

The only REAL way to tell, in any particular use-case, is to build "with" and "without" the extra shared library, and measure the actual performance.